# Track down internet PCs communication using network media devices?

Tags: networking, media, tracking, packet

We are having a little argument here about whether there is a way for internet providers to trace your traffic using the network media devices they are using.

Some of the folks say that if you are using another machine (let's say you have access to someone's computer without him knowing) and you are using HTTPS, there is no way to track you down.

But is it possible, if you have access to media devices between your PC and the one you are using to making requests, to track that packets are send between the two destinations?

I know that in the bottom level OS layers there are the SourceIP and DestionatonIP only for next door devices (we can have many media devices - hops). I don't have much knowledge about this, but using the routing tables or other stuff, is it possible to track the mention above activity down?

After all, there are a lot of proxies and secure networks, but there could not be secrets for the devices that are managing the communication?

Comment: Are you asking about packet sniffers?

Comment: As I have read the "Packet Sniffing" can be use only in internal network. I am more curious of can the owners of media devices use something like this tool to observer all packets in the network and eventually detect if someone is using the PC of other one to send request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By "network media device" do you mean "router"?

If you're using HTTPS, it's possible for ths ISP to tell who is connecting to which site but not what the content of the traffic is.

If you're using a VPN, it's possible to tell that you are using a VPN, but unless the snooper has access to the ISP at the other end of the VPN as well, it's not possible to tell which sites you are connecting to.

Comment: Yes, I mean routers, switches, hubs - all network inter media available.Could you give more details of how the ISP is detecting who is connecting to which site? I suppose but looking through the routing tables?

Comment: By looking at the packets, all of which carry source and destination IP addresses. Packet sniffing works on any network.

Comment: I have thought that this is a program that can be used only for internal networks or if we are talking for ISP, they could use it to observe the traffic between all computers that they provided. Is this true?

Comment: For ISPs, they can see the traffic of all their customers, to and from the rest of the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I suppose that they can do this :- ]